# regexp_like similar function in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I was trying to solve a problem in SQL and I came across the problem:

Query the list of `CITY` names from `STATION` table that do not start with vowels. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

[image]

I used `regexp_like()` function using Oracle but how I can query the results using MySQL?

In Oracle I did `regexp_like(city, '^[^aeiou]', 'i')`

Comment: no idea why it was downvoted. Just stumbled on similar issue so +1

Comment: mysql version is important.  EX: 5.7 uses keyword REGEXP.  Mysql 8.0 states that REGEXP and RLIKE are synonyms of REGEXP_LIKE despite different syntax around where the field name goes.  5.7 will report "FUNCTION $dbname.REGEXP_LIKE does not exist"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL has a `REGEXP` keyword for just such an occasion.

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE field REGEXP 'expression';
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html (first Google result for MySQL REGEXP)

Comment: Can't you add "do not start with vowels" example also?

Comment: What regular expression did you use in Oracle? It'd be the same one here.

Comment: I know REGEXP exits in MySQL but I am getting problem in writing regex for "do not start with vowels" . It will be helpful if you can explain me the regex inside REGEXP function :)
I used regexp_like(city, '^[^aeiou]', 'i');

Comment: So what happens when you use the same `^[^aeiou]` expression in MySQL?

Comment: When I use the query " select distinct city from station where CITY LIKE  '^[^aeiou]'; "  , I get the response as "Wrong Answer"

Comment: Take a closer look at my query. There is no `LIKE` in there anywhere. There's a `REGEXP`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select distinct City 
from Station 
where Left(Upper(city),1)) 
not like '%[AEIOU]%'
```

Comment: While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.